# Magento- How to roll back all the database changes when extension is uninstalled

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have made an extension which, when installed, creates new tables and modify's few existing tables of magento.

how to roll back these database changes in magento database when my magento extension is uninstalled from Magento Connect Manager?

Comment: see/log if any events are fired before and after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have to do that manually. Normally you can see all the changes that have been made in your database in the SQL folder of your plugin:

app\code\local\Company\Module_name\sql\module_name_setup

Comment: @Lrrr MySQL InnoDB tables are transactional, what he's talking about rolling back are the additions of columns to existing tables and added tables to the Magento database much later than what a transactional database cares about. Transactional databases are worried about the proper committing of data to their tables, not the rolling back of major changes to their schema.